# Javascript file not loading in express / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem where my javascript file is not loading. Here is my file directory:

app/views/methods.js
app/views/methods.handlebars

I want to load the methods.js file in the methods.handlebars page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./views/methods.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstNum">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Second Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="secondNum">
  </div>
  <button type="" name="calculate" class="btn btn-default">Calculate</button>
</div>
```

However, I keep getting a cannot GET error in the console... can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: keep methods.js in public directory and do src="/methods.js" or  src="domain.com/methods.js" because after html file is sent to client, it vl try to fetch script methods.js and in views directory it's not publically accessible

Comment: Have you configures express static to serve static files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be related to it being in the Views directory.

Try creating a directory for scripts in the public directory.

So assuming you create a javascript directory that would make your call to get the script as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/methods.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi - I did the following:

- added `app.use(express.static('public'));` to my server.js file
- added a `app/public/javascript` directory and placed my methods.js file in it
- changed my script declaration to `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/methods.js"></script> `

but I'm still getting the same issue.. am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total noob at this - i forgot that I need to reset the node server whenever i make server-side code changes. What I have totally works.